# how to send message at specific time with aiohttp web server?

Tags: python, web, server, aiohttp

I can use the following way to send message when I open one website(http://localhost:api/notify).
I want to send message at the specific time(eg. 5 pm everyday)automatically, how can i do that?

```
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web import Request, Response, json_response

async def notify() :  
    await _send_proactive_message()
    return Response(status=201, text="Proactive messages have been sent")


APP = web.Application()
APP.router.add_get("/api/notify", notify)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        web.run_app(APP, host="localhost")

    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```